# C# ssl/tls with socket tcp

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp

I am new in C# development. I am trying to use ssl/tls over tcp but in my code, system.net.sockets.socket (bare socket) is used not tcpclient or tcplistner. I have searched over net atleast 200 links but I didn't get anything related that. I want to use less coding and done ssl or tsll over tcp socket connection. I have client, server, ca certificate, key in .key format. Please help with example or link. You can ask questions if u feel more details.

Answer (score 29):

Why don't you want to use `TcpClient`? Creating a SSL connection with `TcpClient` and `Ssltream` is quite easy. Unless you require thousands of simultaneous connections I would stick with `TcpClient` and `SSLStream`.

A basic `TcpClient` and `SslStream` example would be as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string server = "127.0.0.1";
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, 443);

    using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null))
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);
        // This is where you read and send data
    }
    client.Close();
}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

High performance socket code can be difficult to write in .NET but there are good examples out there. You have a number of choices. I'm not sure one solution fits all so I'll list a few here.

1. Using an [[Asynchronous Client Socket]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx) maybe be a good place to start
2. There are a few existing libraries you can make use of. I've used [Nito/Async](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) however I don't think it has been updated since 2009. There was talk of a version 2 but I don't believe it materialized.
3. I'm not familar with it but CodeProject has [C# SocketAsyncEventArgs High Performance Socket Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod)
4. Review Microsoft's guidance, [High Performance .NET Socket Server Using Async Winsock](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/High-Performance-NET-69c2df2f)
5. Read everything that Stephen Toub has to say including [Awaiting Socket Operations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/12/15/awaiting-socket-operations/)

I didn't address SSL specifically but look into the `SslStream` Class.

You'll also want to look into buffer pooling. If you're serving thousands of clients garbage collection will be a problem. An excellent introduction to this is [Sunny Ahuwanya's Blog](http://ahuwanya.net/blog/post/Buffer-Pooling-for-NET-Socket-Operations)

---

https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx

before.

Comment: So much effort put in this response, but sadly, this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: What is the relation between the github repo AsyncEx?

Comment: what would be a correct validate certificate routine? in your example you are returning only `true`

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use [`System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd8fz0y3(v=vs.110).aspx) to wrap your socket and then [`System.Net.Security.SslStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddsd3shb(v=vs.110).aspx) to wrap the network stream.

```
Socket socket;
Stream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
Stream sslStream = new SslStream(networkStream);
```

Comment: This answer looks simple enough. Just one doubt: Does this mean that after we wrap the socket like this, we should not use socket.send(), and we should use sslStream throughout? I ask because I already have a working project with Async sockets using Begin/End for send/receive, and it works fine. Use SSL is planned as only an option in the application, so I'm trying to figure out how much change I'll need to do to implement it. Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Absolutely yes, use the ssl stream only, otherwise data will not be read properly by the other side

Comment: You could use this to agree on a key and then use AES over your connection. Create and encrypt your bytes, then send them like you would normally.