# C#: Connect to Gmail's SMTP server via socket

Tags: c#, sockets, email, smtp

I am trying to connect to Gmail's SMTP server via C# sockets. I know there are classes for this very purpose, but I'm learning the SMTP protocol and I'm trying to implement it's functionality. Basically what I want is to be able to send SMTP commands to Gmail's SMTP server and get responses, but I'm running into issues. My code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry("smtp.gmail.com");
        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(host.AddressList[0], 465);
        socket.Connect(endpoint);

        Receive(socket);
        Send(socket, string.Format("HELO {0}\r\n", Dns.GetHostName()));
        Receive(socket);
    }
}

static void Send(Socket socket, string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(">> {0}", message);
    socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
}

static void Receive(Socket socket)
{
    var buffer = new byte[500];
    socket.Receive(buffer);
    Console.WriteLine("<< {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
}
```

My problems with this are:

1. It takes a very long time to finish this program, even though it should be quite fast.
2. The response is always empty. But if I try to run this same code with the port set to `587`, I get normal responses.

I've tested the full workflow of sending an email using the command line and connecting with `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -crlf -ign_eof` and it worked perfectly.

Is there something I'm getting wrong? If so, what might it be? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's SMTP is protected by TLS - you'll have to implement the encryption instead of writing bare data to it.

You might want to consider switching to `TcpClient` and `SslStream` instead of manually doing the `Socket`.

This post has some guidance: [C# ssl/tls with socket tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304612/c-sharp-ssl-tls-with-socket-tcp)