# Should https:// be included or omitted for Host header on a HTTP Request?

Tags: c#, firebase, sockets, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to connect to my Firebase real time database using sockets in C# to send a get request but I am getting either `400 Bad Request` or `400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port` responses. I'm able to establish a connection to `https://<mydatabase>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app` on port `443`. Then I created the below HTTP get request string (replicated what is shown with curl -v command) and send it over the socket like this:

```
StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder();
bob.Append("GET /.json HTTP/1.1\r\n");
bob.Append("Host: https://<mydatabase>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app\r\n");
bob.Append("Accept: */*\r\n\r\n");

Socket socket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect("<mydatabase>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app", 443);
socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bob.ToString()));
```

Then I read from the socket and response is like this:

```
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2023 20:17:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I've checked from both curl & postman and their difference to my payload that I find is this:

```
Host: https://<mydatabase>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app   // My Host header value
Host: <mydatabase>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app           // Host header value on curl and postman although I've provided the https:// on the url
```

And when I omit https:// on my Host header value the response changes to this:

```
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2023 20:20:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 248
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to get the data I'm requesting with URL `https://<mydatabase>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/.json` from both curl and postman. So I don't understand what is different on what I am doing with sockets here. I would appreciate any help or pointers, thanks.

Comment: You are opening a socket and sending the bytes that represent your request. That would be fine for http: on port 80. But you are not handling the SSL/TLS negotiation required by https:. Which raises the questions - why are you working at the level of sockets? and is there a reason for avoiding use of the [HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: The host header does not include the protocol. The format is `Host: <host>[:<port>]`.

Comment: @JonathanDodds My aim is implementing a client for SSE with a C++ framework, where HTTP requests are supported but SSE are not (afaik). Currently I'm trying to understand how a request would work with sockets (on C# because socket usage feels simpler) before skipping to the next step.

I've wrapped my socket with SslStream [shown like this in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304612/c-sharp-ssl-tls-with-socket-tcp). Using SslStream to read/write now gives `400 Bad Request`. Does it mean I've handled the SSL/TLS problem but now missing something Firebase requires on my request?

Comment: Is Firebase is providing any error detail in the body of the response or in a server-side log file?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Unfortunately no, I don't see anything neither in console nor in the response itself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in the title is no. You should only pass the host name in the host name header:
`<mydatabase>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app`

But that is not going to solve your problem. Your code sends a plain text http request to the server but it expects a TLS handshake. When connecting to a TLS endpoint you need to follow the TLS protocol.

S after connecting the remote socket you need to perform a TLS handshake to negotiate security details such as which encryption algorithm to use and establishing a temporary symmetric encryption key used for the duration of the tcp session. Both Postman and curl will handle this transparently for you when they see https in the url.

You most likely do not want to learn TLS and write the low level code yourself. Two possible options are:

1. Use the `SslStream` class to wrap the sockets `NetworkStream` and the call `AuthenticateAsClient()` to perform the handshake.
2. Use the `HttpClient` class and it will transparently take care of TLS for you.

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
var url = "https://<mydatabase>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/.json";
var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```